# Swift : How to set IBOutlet from another controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to hide my IBOutlet. However, setting text to empy string works perfectly fine, but when I acces directly my IBOutlet I keep getting error that "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value".

I tried setting my IBOutlet to local varialble, but it gives error as well. I prepared some code snippets with irrelevant lines deleted just to better expose my problem without providing too much code:

**PageContentViewController**

```
@IBOutlet weak var LabelTop: UILabel!
var Test:UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.LabelTop = self.Test   
}
```

**PageViewController**

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int)-> PageContentViewController?{

    if((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count))
    {
        return nil
    }

    var pageContentViewController: PageContentViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index]
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index]
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
    if(index == 2){

    pageContentViewController.Test.hidden = true
    }
    else {
        pageContentViewController.Test.hidden = false
    }

    return pageContentViewController

}
```

The program crashes when trying to access the UIlabel in if statement. Obviously, as I said before, I can easily access text property and set it to an empty string, but I wonder why IBOutlet is unreachable this way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you getting is that in `viewControllerAtIndex` method you trying to set the outlet but the view controller (PageContentViewController) was not loaded to the view hierarchy so the outlet is still nil.

One of the solution you can use is add a property to the PageContentViewController for example `isHidden` and in viewDidAppear check that property and hide the view or show it:

```
var isHidden:Bool = true 
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    superviewDidAppear(animated)

    self.Test.hidden = isHidden
}
```

in the `viewControllerAtIndex` method change the lines which set up hidden property of the Test control to isHidden:

```
if(index == 2){

    pageContentViewController.isHidden = true
    }
    else {
        pageContentViewController.isHidden = false
    }
```

Comment: Now the error occurs in self.Test.hidden =  isHidden

Comment: @DCDC what error are you getting? Have you created the Test label? I can see that LabelTop is an Outlet so you added it in IB but the Test is not IBOutlet so I assume that you had created it before viewDidAppear fired.

Comment: Ok, this Test variable is the thing that messes up. When I access UIlabel directly self.LabelTop error is not occuring anymore

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `" var Test:UILabel! "` which is `not optional`, 
so in this case, first you have to initialize it.
You are directly accessing its properties without initializing, this is not possible.

Either you need to create Test as `" var Test:UILabel? "` and then create Test programmatically and set its all other properties like text and all.

OR you can create `Boolean variable` in your next class `PageContentViewController`, set Boolean variable value instead of setting `" pageContentViewController.Test.hidden "` value, then after in `PageContentViewController` hide/show your label.